# Bootstrap table border visible before table loaded

Tags: html, user-interface, border

I am loading a bootstrap table filled with data on my Web Page. However before I even press the execute button for the API call to be made and fetch my data, the table borders are already visible on the page like this.

The data is being filled into the tbody in js and this is the code present in my HTML. I think i need to remove the table-bordered here and put it somewhere else so it's only loaded once needed.

```html
<div class="fullcycle-table" id="event-table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks so much for any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the display to none or block based on whether the required data is fetched?
like :
`document.getElementById("someId").style.display = "none";`